# Jekyll layouts looking in the wrong directory

Tags: jekyll

I have a new Jekyll site I'm building and I'd like to use some of the configs to alter the folder layout for what will be a large content site.

I'm trying to move all the content into a directory called `content` and keep the layout and all the core layouts, plugins, etc slightly out of the way of the content.

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
demo-site:
  _layouts:
    main.html

  content:
    index.md

  _config.yml
  Gemfile
  ...
```

My `_config.yml` is very basic:

```
source: ./content
layouts_dir: ../_layouts
markdown: kramdown
```

And my `index.md` is:

```
---
layout: main
---
hello world
```

However, when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I see a warning of:

```
Error reading file /Users/d2kagw/Desktop/demo-site/_layouts/main.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/d2kagw/Desktop/demo-site/content/Users/d2kagw/Desktop/demo-site/_layouts/main.html
```

Clearly, Jekyll is trying to load it from a funky directory tree.

Bug? Or weird quirk with the expected value for `layouts_dir`?

I'm using Jekyll 3.8.3.

Comment: Layouts cannot be outside of source dir.